# Allocating a buffer on the heap at runtime

Tags: memory-management, rust, heap-memory, ownership

I am learning Rust by writing simple binary decoder.

I'm using a `BufferedReader` with the [byteorder crate](https://github.com/BurntSushi/byteorder) to read numbers, but I'm having problems with reading byte buffers.

I want to read byte data into buffer allocated at runtime.
Then I want to pass ownership of this buffer to a struct. When struct is no longer in use, the buffer should be deallocated.

There seems to be no way to allocate array with size determined at runtime on heap except some `Vec::with_capacity()` hacks. Any ideas how to implement this with proper Rust semantics?

Comment: Your question seems to be closer to "How can I use the functionality of `box` in stable code". Perhaps you should update your title.

Comment: Just a point of "semantics": `box` *is* proper Rust, it's just not stable Rust for now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rust is a low-level language; thus you can allocate raw memory and then fill it with objects yourself. Of course, it will require `unsafe` code, as all fiddling with raw memory does.

Here is [a complete example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cf7bcba8cb9c68a2058b36905c960197):

```
use std::{
    alloc::{self, Layout},
    mem, ptr,
};

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let layout = Layout::from_size_align(512 * 1024, 4 * 1024).expect("Invalid layout");
        let mut raw: *mut i32 = mem::transmute(alloc::alloc(layout));

        for i in 0..(512 * 1024 / 4) {
            ptr::write(raw, i as i32);
            raw = raw.offset(1)
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, in real code, I would just use `Vec` to safely manage the memory for me. It's just simpler!

Comment: *fill it with objects yourself* — is it worth mentioning zero-sized types and destructors and all the other complexities that explain why `Vec` is better to use? Any maybe use `as *mut i32` instead of `transmute`? And maybe use `mem::size_of` instead of hard coding `4`? And for my own curiosity, why align the memory to a 4K chunk? +1 for "just use `Vec`" ^_^.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I hesitated in enumerating plenty of potential issues, but I was afraid it would just sound like rambling...

Comment: One day, you can be a professional rambler, such as myself! ;-)

Answer (score 11):

This will create a pre-allocated mutable 500MB byte buffer of zeros stored on the heap with no need for unsafe rust:

// Correct

```rust
let mut buffer = vec![0_u8; 536870912];
```

Note that the following code below is not a good idea and will most likely result in a stack overflow because the buffer is created on the stack before being boxed and moved to the heap.

// Incorrect - stack used

```rust
let mut bytes: Box<[u8]> = Box::new([0_u8; 536870912])
```

// Incorrect - slow

```rust
let mut bytes = Vec::with_capacity(536870912);
for _ in 0..bytes.capacity() {
    bytes.push(0_u8);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using `box` but it seems that it is experimental and I can't use it with release branch. Any ideas how to implement this with proper Rust semantics?

This is covered in *[The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/)*, specifically the section "[Using Box<T> to Point to Data on the Heap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch15-01-box.html)".

Use [`Box::new`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html):

```rust
fn main() {
    let answer: Box<u8> = Box::new(42);
}
```

See also:

- [Allocate array onto heap with size known at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41710952/155423)
- [Is there any way to allocate a standard Rust array directly on the heap, skipping the stack entirely?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53691012/155423)
- [How to allocate arrays on the heap in Rust 1.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30242770/155423)
- [Creating a fixed-size array on heap in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25805174/155423)
- [How do I allocate an array at runtime in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34399277/155423)
- [Thread '<main>' has overflowed its stack when allocating a large array using Box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28249292/155423)

Comment: Yes, `Box::new` creates variable on heap. But to my knowledge, calling `Box::new` creates variable on the stack, and function call will copy it to heap. `box <expr>` syntax should create right on heap AFAIK. That might be a problem since I want to create 512 KB buffers.

Comment: @semtexzv can you point to some documentation or disassembly that corroborates that? The optimizers underlying Rust (provided by LLVM) are pretty strong.

Comment: `let mut xx = Box::new([0u8;5000000]);` causes stack overflow. It should allocate 5 megs of data. But I'm probably understanding this wrong.

Comment: @semtexzv not if you [compile in release mode](http://is.gd/uHPkP0), which enables optimizations.

Comment: @semtexzv Also, if you were aware of `Box::new` but didn't want to use it, you should have included those restrictions in your question.

Comment: Problem is not using `Box::new` problem is allocating  an array at runtime directly on heap.