# Is there any way to allocate a standard Rust array directly on the heap, skipping the stack entirely?

Tags: arrays, rust, heap-memory

There are several questions already on Stack Overflow about allocating an array (say `[i32]`) on the heap.  The general recommendation is boxing, e.g. `Box<[i32]>`.  But while boxing works fine enough for smaller arrays, the problem is that the array being boxed has to first be allocated on the stack.

So if the array is too large (say 10 million elements), you will - even with boxing - get a stack overflow (one is unlikely to have a stack that large).

The suggestion then is using `Vec<T>` instead, that is `Vec<i32>` in our example.  And while that does do the job, it does have a performance impact.

Consider the following program:

```
fn main() {
    const LENGTH: usize = 10_000;
    let mut a: [i32; LENGTH] = [0; LENGTH];
    for j in 0..LENGTH {
        for i in 0..LENGTH {
            a[i] = j as i32;
        }
    }
}
```

`time` tells me that this program takes about 2.9 seconds to run.  I use 10'000 in this example, so I can allocate that on the stack, but I really want one with 10 million.

Now consider the same program but with `Vec<T>` instead:

```
fn main() {
    const LENGTH: usize = 10_000;
    let mut a: Vec<i32> = vec![0; LENGTH];
    for j in 0..LENGTH {
        for i in 0..LENGTH {
            a[i] = j as i32;
        }
    }
}
```

`time` tells me that this program takes about 5 seconds to run.  Now `time` isn't super exact, but the difference of about 2 seconds for such a simple program is not an insignificant impact.

Storage is storage, the program with array is just as fast when the array is boxed.  So it's not the heap slowing the `Vec<T>` version down, but the `Vec<T>` structure itself.

I also tried with a `HashMap` (specifically `HashMap<usize, i32>` to mimic an array structure), but that's far slower than the `Vec<T>` solution.

If my `LENGTH` had been 10 million, the first version wouldn't even have run.

If that's not possible, is there a structure that behaves like an array (and `Vec<T>`) on the heap, but can match the speed and performance of an array?

Comment: *There are several questions already on Stack Overflow about allocating an array* — And how is **this one** different? Just because you don't like existing answers doesn't mean that you can open a duplicate.

Comment: @Shepmaster My question was about performance as well.  The other questions never raised this issue.  The answer below also explores this aspect and answers it well.

Comment: I've come across this question because I'm having the same issue, but my reason for not wanting to use `Vec` is different: I want to still be able to use the compile-time type checker to catch length mismatches (e.g. in matrix-vector multiplication, where the matrices and vectors are statically sized). `Vec` won't help me accomplish this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

***Summary*: your benchmark is flawed; just use a `Vec` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242770/how-to-allocate-arrays-on-the-heap-in-rust-1-0)), possibly with [`into_boxed_slice`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_boxed_slice),  as it is incredibly unlikely to be slower than a heap allocated array.**

---

Unfortunately, your benchmarks are flawed. First of all, you probably didn't compile with optimizations (`--release` for cargo, `-O` for rustc). Because if you would have, the Rust compiler would have removed all of your code. See [the assembly here](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/OJY4W-). Why? Because you never observe the vector/array, so there is no need to do all that work in the first place.

Also, your benchmark is not testing what you actually want to test. You are comparing an stack-allocated array with a heap-allocated vector. You should compare the `Vec` to a heap allocated array.

Don't feel bad though: writing benchmarks is incredible hard for many reasons. Just remember: if you don't know a lot about writing benchmarks, better don't trust your own benchmarks without asking others first.

---

I fixed your benchmark and included all three possibilities: `Vec`, array on stack and array on heap. You can find the full code [here](https://gist.github.com/LukasKalbertodt/7eaf9399d3a3220dae16ef64a46f0ba9). The results are:

```
running 3 tests
test array_heap  ... bench:   9,600,979 ns/iter (+/- 1,438,433)
test array_stack ... bench:   9,232,623 ns/iter (+/- 720,699)
test vec_heap    ... bench:   9,259,912 ns/iter (+/- 691,095)
```

Surprise: the difference between the versions are way less than the variance of the measurement. So we can assume they all are pretty equally fast.

Note that this benchmark is *still* pretty bad. The two loops can just be replaced by one loop setting all array elements to `LENGTH - 1`. From taking a quick look at the assembly (and from the rather long time of 9ms), I think that LLVM is not smart enough to actually perform this optimization. But things like this are important and one should be aware of that.

---

Finally, let's discuss why both solutions should be equally fast and whether there are actually differences in speed.

The data section of a `Vec<T>` has exactly the same memory layout as a `[T]`: just many `T`s contiguously in memory. Super simple. This also means both exhibit the same caching-behavior (specifically, being very cache-friendly).

The only difference is that a `Vec` might have more capacity than elements. So `Vec` itself stores `(pointer, length, capacity)`. That is one word more than a simple (boxed) slice (which stores `(pointer, length)`). A boxed array doesn't need to store the length, as it's already in the type, so it is just a simple pointer. Whether or not we store one, two or three words is not really important when you will have millions of elements anyway.

Accessing one element is the same for all three: we do a bounds check first and then calculate the target pointer via `base_pointer + size_of::<T>() * index`. But it's important to note that the array storing its length in the type means that the bounds check can be removed more easily by the optimizer! This can be a real advantage.

However, bounds checks are already usually removed by the smart optimizer. In the benchmark code I posted above, there are no bounds checks in the assembly. So while a boxed array could be a bit faster by removed bounds checks, (a) this will be a minor performance difference and (b) it's very unlikely that you will have a lot of situations where the bound check is removed for the array but not for the Vec/slice.

Comment: You are absolutely right, the difference was made with the optimiser.  Compiling my larger program with `-O`, there is no performance impact using `Vec<T>`.  Thank you for the in depth answer.  So the answer to my question is just to keep using `Vec<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a heap-allocated array, i.e. `Box<[i32; LENGTH]>` then you can use:

```rust
fn main() {
    const LENGTH: usize = 10_000_000;

    let mut a = {
        let mut v: Vec<i32> = Vec::with_capacity(LENGTH);

        // Explicitly set length which is safe since the allocation is
        // sized correctly.
        unsafe { v.set_len(LENGTH); };

        // While not required for this particular example, in general
        // we want to initialize elements to a known value.
        let mut slice = v.into_boxed_slice();
        for i in &mut slice[..] {
            *i = 0;
        }

        let raw_slice = Box::into_raw(slice);

        // Using `from_raw` is safe as long as the pointer is
        // retrieved using `into_raw`.
        unsafe {
            Box::from_raw(raw_slice as *mut [i32; LENGTH])
        }
    };

    // This is the micro benchmark from the question.
    for j in 0..LENGTH {
        for i in 0..LENGTH {
            a[i] = j as i32;
        }
    }
}
```

It's not going to be faster than using a vector since Rust does bounds-checking even on arrays, but it has a smaller interface which might make sense in terms of software design.

Comment: Any time you use `unsafe`, but especially on Stack Overflow, you should add a comment explaining why you believe it is correct. In this particular case, why it's OK to leave the Vec's elements uninitialized, and why it's OK to use `Box::from_raw` on the casted pointer.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour. The elements of a `[T]` must be initialised.

Comment: More precisely, read the safety documentation for `unsafe fn set_len()`. “The elements at `old_len..new_len` must be initialized.”