# How to create huge array in Rust directly on the heap, skipping stack?

Tags: arrays, rust, stack-overflow, heap-memory

I need to declare and initialize array with size at least 8GB (1 billion of f64 variables). Everything I've tried so far is very complicated or inefficient or gives STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW (0xC00000FD) error because it's first being created on heap.

How can I do it efficiently, clean and nice?

[Is there any way to allocate a standard Rust array directly on the heap, skipping the stack entirely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691012/is-there-any-way-to-allocate-a-standard-rust-array-directly-on-the-heap-skippin)
Solutions proposed here use Vec, which does have performance impact.

Comment: `vec![0.0f64; 1_000_000]`

Comment: Vec has performance impact. I need raw array to reduce memory usage and increase performanceas much as possible.

Comment: Note the first words of the first answer: *Summary: your benchmark is flawed; just use a `Vec`*. Please show _your_ benchmark that backs up the claim "Vec, which does have performance impact."

Comment: Also note that there are [**multiple answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56426372/155423)

Comment: Doesn't Vec store additional data compared to array?

Comment: Other answer uses unsafe keyword which I want to avoid.

Comment: It does. A `Vec` of a billion elements will also take up 3x `usize` values. On a 64-bit machine, a `Vec` will have the "overhead" of 24 bytes. Compared to your other memory allocation of *gigabytes*, I think you can spare it.

Comment: Since this array is heap allocated, you'd still need at least 8 of those bytes to reach it; if its size is not statically known then you'd need another 8 bytes for that (i.e. together being the 16 bytes of the slice reference).  So the overhead of `Vec` is actually 8 or 16 bytes, not 24.