# Why doesn't vec![[EMPTY; SIZEY]; SIZEX] produce the type Vec<[[i32; SIZEY]; SIZEX]>?

Tags: rust

This program is fine:

```
const EMPTY: i32 = 0;
const SIZEX: usize = 4;
const SIZEY: usize = 4;

fn main() {
    let mut test = vec![[EMPTY; SIZEY]; SIZEX];
    test[2][3] = 4;
    // test.what();
    println!("Hello, world:{}", test[2][3]);
}
```

When I uncomment the `test.what()` line to see the type of `test`, the compiler emits the error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `what` found for struct `Vec<[i32; 4]>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:8:10
  |
8 |     test.what();
  |          ^^^^ method not found in `Vec<[i32; 4]>`
```

I was expecting that the type of `test` would be something like `Vec<[[i32; SIZEY]; SIZEX]>`. What am I missing?

Comment: What's `.what()`?

Comment: The types to look here are [the array primitive](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.array.html) and [`std::vec::Vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html). Might be worth reading about both here.

Answer (score 1):

The `vec![t; N]` macro will make a `Vec<T>` (where `T` is the type of `t`) of length `N`. The length isn't part of the type since it is dynamic.

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked the fact that the length was not in the type, which is obvious as soon as you remember that Vec are dynamic arrays. I explicitly didn't want an array as I am looking for heap allocated (very large) arrays. And I have also tested the "Box"  trick to create box arrays with vec.into_boxed_slice()

Comment: I'm assuming you've seen the answers here: [Is there any way to allocate a standard Rust array directly on the heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53691012/2189130)